# how to hanlde response status with axios async await

Tags: async-await, axios

I have below snippet

```
const url = 'https://someurl.com';
const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            data: {
                property_one: value_one,
                property_two: value_two
            }
        };
const response = await axios(options);
const responseOK = response && response.status === 200 && response.statusText === 'OK';
if (responseOK) {
    const data = await response.data;
    // do something with data
}
```

Do we need to check both **response.status** and **response.statusText**? Additionally, if **response.data** has additonal status coming from back-end for example:

```
{
      "transactionId": "123456789",
      "document": {
        "documentId": "123456",
        "status": "S"
      }
}
```

Do we need to check the **status is "S"**. If yes, how we can check along with **response.status** and **response.statusText**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle request and response in `trycatch` statement

request:

```
try {
    const res = await axios.post('url', body);
    //continue with res.data

} catch (err) {
    const error = err.response.data;
    //throw alert or something
}
```

response:

```
try {
    //query
    res.status(200).json(data);

} catch (err) {
    //error
    res.status(500).json('Server Error');
}
```